# I am trying to upload the captured/ selected image from gallery to my server but it is giving below error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, upload, server

```
 class ImageGalleryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
            InputStream is;
            BitmapFactory.Options bfo;
            Bitmap bitmapOrg;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao ;
           // ImageView imgshoot = null;
            bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bfo.inSampleSize = 2;
           // bitmapOrg =   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + customImage, bfo);
    //      bitmap = mark(bitmap, "Hallo");



            bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bao);
            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bao.toByteArray()));
            String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd","image_android"));
            Log.v("log_tag", System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");           
            try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new 
                  //  Here you need to put your server file address
                    HttpPost("http://192.168.0.1/Upload/UploadImg.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" );
               }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
               }
        return "Success";
        // (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

this is the error which  is displayed in Logcat:

> 02-16 14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()  02-16 14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
>
> 02-16 14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>   02-16 14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>   02-16 14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) 02-16
>   14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 02-16
>   14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   02-16 14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   02-16 14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 02-16 14:44:05.872:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9375): Caused by:
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   02-16 14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6603) 02-16
>   14:44:05.872: E/AndroidRuntime(9375):     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:954)

I am even adding my server code which is stored in php file: (check.php):

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "Upload/";
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    $name=$_REQUEST['cmd'];
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
      header('Content-Type: jpeg; charset=utf-8');
   $file = fopen($target_path, 'wb');
   $file = fopen($name, 'wb');
   fwrite($file, $binary);
   fclose($file);
    //move_uploaded_file($file,$target_path.$name);
      copy($name,$target_path.$name);
     ?>
```

Comment: check this https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/

Comment: because of this imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap).  You cannot do UI operations in  doInBackground(), perform all UI related operations in onPreExecute() on onPostExecute()

Comment: do we need to create any database to store images when storing php file in server. where the uploaded image will be stored?? I am new to php programming so cant get it... @techroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); with

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: then you should add imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); in onPostExecute

Comment: I tried doing that but my doInBackgroud code doesnt execute only... would you like to see my php file which contains server side code??

Comment: you have not written imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); in post execute that is written out of postExecute

Comment: Dont use base 64 for image uploading use multipart.

Comment: can u suggest me anythi9ng about multipart...??

Comment: by using multipart you cant upload heavy images with bug free code

Comment: follow this link this is working fine http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackground(), you have written  `imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`which is not acceptable.You should write background operations in that method.

There are many tutorials.Hope It ll be helpful.
Try this [example](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/)

Comment: do we need to create any database to store images when storing php file in server. where the uploaded image will be stored?? I am new to php programming so cant get it...

Comment: Check this example...http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample